# Value out of range error, vba ppt

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm making a loop presentation in PowerPoint and I need a countdown to a specific date.

When using the code below i get following error:

Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)':
The specified value is out of range.

```
Sub Countdown()
Dim thedate As Date
Dim daycount As Long
Dim Icount As Integer
Icount = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Count - 1
thedate = "25/12/2013"
daycount = DateDiff("d", Now, thedate)
Select Case daycount
    Case Is > 1
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(Icount) _
        .TextFrame.TextRange = daycount & " Days to go!"
    Case Is = 1
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(Icount) _
        .TextFrame.TextRange = daycount & " Day to go!"
    Case Else
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(Icount) _
        .TextFrame.TextRange = "It's here!"
End Select
End Sub
```

Please help me!

Comment: which line you get the error? how many slides are there in you presentation? try to change `thedate` into `2013-12-25`... try to add `.Text` property after all `.TextRange`...

Answer (score 0):

You need hash-signs to delimit a Date value

```
thedate = #12/25/2013#
```

and it is in the order mm/dd/yyyy.

Also remember that VBA collections are indexed from 1, so Shapes(countOfShapes) will be the last Shape.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
Icount = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Count - 1
.....
Select Case daycount
    Case Is > 1
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(Icount) _
```

If there's only one shape on the slide, ICount will be 0
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(Icount) will then throw an error